# Binding data dynamically in ListView2 on Selected_indexChanged() of ListView1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I am working in a project where i need to list the database **child** items in **listview2** who's **parent** items reside in **listview1** already. here is my **listview1** code;

```
 <asp:ListView    
 ID="ListView1"OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">  
 <ItemTemplate>
 <a href='<%# Eval("Module_Redirect") %>'> <img src="<%# 
 Eval("Module_img") %>" /> </a> 
 </ItemTemplate>
```

the .cs page code is as follow(which is not working yet!)

```
 protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.ListView1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da2.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Forms where Module_ID=3 ", conn);
            DataTable dt2= new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            ListView2.DataSource = dt2;
            ListView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

My point is: **how can in fetch the selected item templete of listview1 and show the relevent record in listview2?**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectioString"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Forms where Module_ID = @Module_ID ", con) })
                {
                    // as your using index as the parameter,,
                    da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Module_ID", ListView1.SelectedIndex);

                    // or if your trying to pass parameter Module_ID from ListView1 DataKey ,, you can use SelectedDataKey
                    //da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Module_ID", ListView1.SelectedDataKey);

                    using (DataTable dt2 = new DataTable())
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        da2.Fill(dt2);

                        ListView2.DataSource = dt2;
                        ListView2.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: thankyou for the code. but it is not working :/.... my listview2 is not responding when i select the listview1's item